# jQuery: load refuses to get dynamic content in IE6

Tags: jquery, dynamic, internet-explorer-6, load

jQuery refuses to load my dynamic content in IE6. All in FireFox & Safari works fine. Only IE6 is being a pain. When I try the a html with

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

that works. Properly. But when loading a PHP it doesn't work!

As you can see it's doing multiple things.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
      $(document).ready(function() {

    // Sort list & amend in database                        
    function sortTableMenuAndReload() {

    var order = $('#menuList').sortable('serialize');
        $.post("PLUGINS/SortableMenu/process-sortable.php",order);
        $("#menuList").load("PLUGINS/SortableMenu/sortableMenu_ajax.php");

    }

    function sortTableOrder() {

    var order = $('#menuList').sortable('serialize');
        $.post("PLUGINS/SortableMenu/process-sortable.php",order);

    }

    function sortTableOrderAndRemove(removeID) {

        $('#listItem_'+removeID).remove();

    var order = $('#menuList').sortable('serialize');
        $.post("PLUGINS/SortableMenu/process-sortable.php",order);
        $("#menuList").load("PLUGINS/SortableMenu/sortableMenu_ajax.php");

    }

        $("#menuList > li > .remove").live('click', function () { 

                var removeID = $(this).attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'PLUGINS/SortableMenu/removeLine.php',
                    data: 'id='+removeID,
                    success: sortTableOrderAndRemove(removeID)
                       });

        });


        $("#menuList > li > .publish").live('click', function () { 

                var publishID = $(this).attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'PLUGINS/SortableMenu/publishLine.php',
                    data: 'id='+publishID,
                    success: sortTableOrder
                       });

        });


        $('#new_documents > li').draggable({
            addClasses: false,
            helper:'clone',
            connectToSortable:'#menuList'
        });


        $("#menuList").droppable({
            addClasses: false,
            drop: function() {
                var clone = $("#menuList > li#newArticleTYPE1");
                $(clone).attr("id","listItem_newArticleTYPE1"); 
            }
        });




        $("#menuList").sortable({
          opacity: 0.6,
          handle : '.handle, .remove',
          update : sortTableMenuAndReload
        });


    });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is!!!

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

This got it fixed!